# Python w/ Selenium Gmail Email Send Automating To: Field is Giving Me Trouble

Tags: python, selenium, automation, gmail

The end goal is to send myself an email if my public ip address changes, as I don't have dynamic dns and have to manually enter the ip addresses myself for my web server. I've done all I possibly can to try and get bash utilities to do the job for me, but CenturyLink is unfortunately out to block me no matter how I configure my outbound mail.

So I've turned to graphical python/selenium web page automation, which will sign into my gmail account for me, click the 'compose' button, then enter in the To:, Subject:, and text segments and hit send. Everything is working except for one small part - the To: field. The html/css is different for this than all the others and no matter how I try to select the field using

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name()
```

or

```
driver.find_element_by_id()
```

I just can't seem to fill out the field. Bash will give me an error like

```
:lo cannot be reached by keyboard
```

or
    textarea#:lo.vO is not a valid selector

When I did an inspect element, the element looked like this:

```
<textarea rows="1" id=":lo" class="vO" name="to" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="false" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" tabindex="1" dir="ltr" aria-label="To" role="combobox" aria-autocomplete="list" style="width: 462px;"></textarea>
```

My code so far is this: (note: which does not include getting ip info yet, just gmail login / manipulation)

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox();
driver.get('https://www.gmail.com');
username = driver.find_element_by_id('identifierId');
username.send_keys("EMAIL");
driver.find_elements_by_class_name('RveJvd.snByac')[1].click();
time.sleep(2); #password not entered in username field
password = driver.find_element_by_class_name('whsOnd.zHQkBf');
password.send_keys("PASSWORD");
driver.find_elements_by_class_name('RveJvd.snByac')[0].click();

#end login, start composing

time.sleep(5); #wait for sign in
driver.find_element_by_class_name('T-I.J-J5-Ji.T-I-KE.L3').click();
to = driver.find_element_by_class_name('textarea#:lo.vO'); #incorrect
to.send_keys("EMAIL");
subject = driver.find_element_by_id(':l6');
subject.send_keys("IP Address changed");
content = driver.find_element_by_id(':m9');
content.send_keys("Test Test\n");
```

Comment: this sounds like an XY problem.  Why is your question about emailing yourself when the issue you are trying to solve is about setting your webserver's IP?

Comment: Hi, seems to be an xpath or element inaccessible issue. Can you add the screen print of gmail login? I will try fetching the xpath

Comment: Just noted that the 'To:' text area element's id changes dynamically while composing message in different browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there seems to be a dynamic variation with the element ids in different browser. For me when I tried to compose the mail to fetch the XPATH I noted the XPATH was `//*[@id=":oa"]` but while the script launched it was `//*[@id=":my"]`.

To accommodate this I have used element querying using XPATH `//textarea[1]` as the Recipients section is always the first `textarea`. This proves to work well consistently across different browser sessions.

**Code Snippet**

```
>>> d = webdriver.Chrome()
[14424:7728:0809/135301.805:ERROR:install_util.cc(597)] Unable to read registry value HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\MachineLevelUserCloudPolicyEnrollmentToken for writing result=2

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:12582/devtools/browser/31a5ab42-a4d2-46f3-95c6-a0c9ddc129d7
>>> d.get('https://www.gmail.com')
>>> d.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="6072286733856e53b69af89ea981001c", element="0.42218760484088036-1")>
>>> d.find_element_by_xpath('//textarea[1]').send_keys('cswadhikar@gmail.com')
```

**Result**

[image: compose]

Comment: ```wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//textarea[1]'))).send_keys("my_email")
```

Did the job for me

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use the Gmail API? 
It's easier faster and more efficient than using Selenium.

Here's the quickstart: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python

(I'm writing an answer because I don't have the reputation to just comment)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Python's built-in email package:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to send an email with Gmail.
It has To, Subject and Send button functionality :

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id=":k2"]/div/div').click()# Compose button
time.sleep(5)

driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'to').send_keys("Enter the email address of recipients")# to field in compose
time.sleep(2)

driver.find_element(By.NAME,'subjectbox').send_keys("This email is send using selenium")# Subject field in compose
time.sleep(2)

driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id=":p3"]').click()# click on send button

time.sleep(5)

driver.close()